# Read LocalStorage Value In .Net Core Web Api

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I read localstorage value when send get request to web api?
currently I am using angular 8 with jwt interceptor which is capable to  read token from localstorage but how can I read all properties of localstorage?

**LocalStorage**

[image]

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
  [Authorize]

    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Index()
    { 
        //READ CurrentRole and Roleaccesslist here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own HttpInterceptor like:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }


    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
            }
        }); return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Or use @auth0/angular-jwt which adds the interceptor for you.

```
export function GetToken() {
   return localStorage.getItem(environment.jwt_name);
 }

 JwtModule.forRoot({
     config: {
       tokenGetter: GetToken,
       whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000', 'localhost:5001']
     }
  }),
```

Comment: @Markel I am not asking about how the token sent to server

Comment: You mean how to read from localstorage in angular? before sending to the API? therefor I use import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';  export function GetToken() {
   return localStorage.getItem(environment.jwt_name);
 } and JwtModule.forRoot({
         config: {
           tokenGetter: GetToken,
           whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000', 'localhost:5001']
         }
       }), Is that what you mean? If so, I'll update my answer

Comment: I just want to send localstorage values

Comment: I updated my answer. I think the title of your question is a bit confusing because it indicates that your want to read localStorage values in asp which is not possible

Comment: I agree. I was confused with title :(